# Mean curvature of a ruled surface in $\mathbb{R}^3$

Tags: differential-geometry

I was trying to prove that non compact surfaces with constant mean and gaussian curvature in $\mathbb R^3$ are part of planes or cylinder. Here is how I worked out the problem so far,

First of all I proved that the gaussian curvature must be zero i.e $K=0$,

Then I used the fact that the surface will be develop-able and hence in this case a ruled surface. I considered a parametrization $x(u,v)=\beta(u)+v\delta(u)$ of the surface, I know that the gaussian curvature in this case is given by $K=\frac{-M^2}{EG-F^2}$ which will imply that $M=0$, Can someone show me how to explicitly compute $H$ in this case? and how can i use the fact that $H$ is constant to prove that $\gamma'(u)=0$, which will prove that it is a cylinder.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

So here is what I think, since $H=\frac{EN-2FM+GL}{2(EG-F^2)}$ in general, and in this case, $N=0$, I will be left with only $H=\frac{LG}{2(EG-F^2)}$, for $H$ to be constant, $L$,$G$and $EG-F^2$ should be constant. How do i get further information form here?

Answer (score 1):

It may be relevant to examine the arguments here proceeding from scalar curvatures.

In terms of principal curvatures $ k_1,k_2 $, when H and K are *both* constant,

$$ k_1 + k_2 = 2 H , k_1 k_2 = K $$ solving,

$$  k_1  = 1/a,  k_2  = 1/b $$ where $a,b$ are constant.

To understand this in case of *surfaces of revolution* :

They are

1) *Toroids,Spheres*  ($ k_1 = const $ ) and,

2) Special cases of *Weingarten surfaces* where $ \dfrac {k_1}{k_2} = const. $

Examples are Spheres, Cycloids and  Elastica special case with meridional

tangent are normal to axis of symmetry.

3) *Minimal surface.*

Applying Quotient Rule,

$$ k_2= const. = \dfrac{\cos \phi }{r}  =  \dfrac {-\sin \phi\; k_1} {\sin \phi} = -k_1 $$

or,

$$ k_1 + k_2 = 2 H =0 $$

which is a catenoid minimal surface, $ r/c = \cosh(z/c) $, an exceptional case for a ruled surface.

But note that these are not ruled surfaces in general nor do they belong only to $K=0$ class of developable surfaces (cones, developable helicoids).

EDIT1:

There is something disconcerting about taking $ K and H $ *independent* though, shall mention it.

For a surface of revolution $ \tan\phi = \frac{dr}{dz} $

Let $$ R_1 = 1/k_1, R_2= 1/k_2 $$

It can be verified that

$$ \dfrac{d R_2}{d\cos\phi} =- (R_1+R_2) $$

so they are not really independent.